# How to call python with script from StdIn from BASH with dynamic input-parameters?

Tags: python, bash, input, command-line, parameters

As part of a BASH-script I need to launch some python-code with an input-parameter.
I also want to avoid creating an temporary *.py-files.

This is what I have so far:

```
input=123
output=$(
python - <<'END_SCRIPT'
print("$input")
END_SCRIPT
)
echo $output
```

This snippet writes the output of the python-call into an output-variable.
But instead of returning "123" it returns "$input", because the variable with not be interpreted during the piping into python.
Is there any way to forward the input variable as a parameter to python while reading from StdIn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```sh
input=123
output=$(python - "$input" <<'END_SCRIPT'
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
END_SCRIPT
)
echo "$output"
```

(Notice also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).)

Comment: As a stylistic choice, you can also put the here document outside the command substitution: `output=$(python - "$input") << 'END_SCRIPT'`, as Python will inherit its standard input from the assignment.

Comment: @chepner I dont get that comment. How to make this into a solution or to improve the given solution?

Comment: @Peter Literally, you just move the `)` to just before the `<<`. Like I said, it's a style choice, not an improvement, as I'm not aware of any significant difference between putting the quoted here-document inside the command substitution versus leaving it outside.

Comment: @chepner I tried moving the bracket, but that does not run at all on MacOS with BASH.

Comment: I can confirm - contrary to my expectation - that Bash 3.2 on MacOS Catalina starts an interactive Python interpreter if you move the redirection outside the command substitution.

Comment: Also the more reason to avoid `bash` 3.2; this is a bug, or at the very least non-POSIX behavior, that was corrected in `bash` 4.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the single quotes around `END_SCRIPT`

```
input=123
output=$(
python - << END_SCRIPT
print("$input")
END_SCRIPT
)
echo $output
```

Comment: This is problematic if the real Python script needs to contain literal backticks or dollar signs anywhere in it.

Comment: @tripleee good call. I edited my answer. I assumed OP has some control over `input` in which case they could escape those characters before passing them to Python

Comment: Making the caller responsible for adapting the input is just asking for mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I decided to skip passing any input variable to python at all and better set an environment variable as needed. Here my final result:

```
input='<123!>'
output=$(python3 - <<'END_SCRIPT'
import os
print(os.environ['input'])
END_SCRIPT
)
echo "$output"
```